# UNIX Search in specific column for user specified code and output entire line

Tags: bash, unix

I'm working on a program that searches a medication list and returns a report as requested by the user. So i am trying to search this list for a code that the user inputs and then return the relevant information.

```
EX. (medcode)           (doseage)
commA6314   ifosfamide  30
home5341209 urokinase   6314
```

When i search the file i only want it to return the line if it finds a match in columns 6-12 (6314 for the first line) but at the moment it will return both lines since the second line also contains 6314. All of the answers i saw used text processing utilities like awk, sed or perl and one of the conditions of the program is not to use any of these utilities.

The programs expected output:

```
 Enter medication code?
 6314
 See Generic name g/G or Dose d/D?
 g
 ifosfamide
```

What i am getting currently:

```
Enter medication code?
6314
See Generic name g/G or Dose d/D?
g
ifosfamide
urokinase
```

so it is also displaying information about the second medication because 6314 is also contained in the columns for doseage.

Comment: Just bash built-ins, or are other utilities like cut ok?

Comment: 6314 is not in column range starting at 5 !

Comment: cut is ok the guidelines just say the program must not use any text processing utilities like awk, sed, or perl.

Comment: And now it's no more 5 but 6 ? What's the point ?

Comment: sorry i edited the question to be more clear. i apologize english is not my first language

Comment: @JesseG Your recent edit gives the appearance of you wanting someone else to do your homework for you.  Typically, StackOverflow doesn't look kindly on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using just [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ ${line%% *} == *6314* ]] && echo "$line"
done < input_file
```

It search only in the medication column.

## explanations

```
${line%% *}
```

is a bash *parameter expansion*, it keep only the first 'word' before the first space

Comment: i edited the question to try and be more clear what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

## Using bash

To match 6314 but only if it starts in column 6 using just bash, try:

```
$ while read -r line; do [[ "$line" =~ ^.{5}6314 ]] && echo "$line"; done <infile
commA6314   ifosfamide  30
```

This reads lines from the file one-by-one.  The line is echoed to output only if it matches the regex `^.{5}6314` which requires that `6314` appear starting at the sixth character from the start of the line.

To print just the second word on the line but only if the first word matches your number position six:

```
$ while read -r code name extra; do [[ "$code" =~ ^.{5}6314 ]] && echo "$name"; done <infile
ifosfamide
```

## Using grep

To match 6314 but only if it starts in column 6, try:

```
$ grep -E '^.{5}6314' infile
commA6314   ifosfamide  30
```

Here, `^` specifies the beginning of a line and `.{5}` matches any five characters.  Thus `^.{5}6314` matches 6314 but only if it starts as the sixth character on the line.

## Using awk

```
$ awk '"6314" == substr($0, 6, 4)' infile
commA6314   ifosfamide  30
```

Here, `substr($0, 6, 4)` selects four characters from the line starting at the sixth.  If this equals `6314`, then the line is printed.

## Using sed

```
$ sed -En '/^.{5}6314/p' infile
commA6314   ifosfamide  30
```

`-n` tells sed not to print unless we explicitly ask it to.  `/^.{5}6314/p` tells sed to print any line that, starting at the sixth character, matches `6314`.

Comment: i edited the question to try and be more clear what i am trying to achieve